# Jackson parse array with both anonymous and named field

Tags: json, jackson

I would like to parse the following json string using Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
["EVENT","event-id",{"content":"{}","created_at":1677781808,"tags":[["t","tag1"]]}]
```

I was trying the following model class:

```
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class Event {

    @JsonProperty
    String event;

    @JsonProperty
    String eventId;



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
            return json;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to parse like this:

```
 Event event = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Event.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected END_ARRAY: Unexpected JSON values; expected at most 2 properties (in JSON Array)
 at [Source: (byte[])"["EVENT","3c1dbf5f-b2b0-478d-9b18-2721a90d5f29",{"content":...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [`JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation to your `Event` class so ignoring the processing of JSON properties not included in your class read during deserialization:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class Event {

    String event;
    String eventId;
}

Event event = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload()
                                      .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Event.class);
//it prints [ "EVENT", "event-id" ]     
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(event));
```

Comment: Thanks! But somehow for me it prints `event=EVENT` instead of just `"EVENT"`,

Comment: @kerner1000 You are welcome, from my side (jackson 2.14) it works fine.